# Filter Django Queryset to return followers of logged in user only

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying work out how filter who follows the logged in user/who is followed by the logged in user using Django Rest Framework. However, all I seem to be returning is ALL users who have been followed by any user or are following any user, it is not specific to the logged in user ([the front end view (numbers are the user PK)](https://ibb.co/bPT5LKr), [the API view](https://ibb.co/55652WD)).

I make a GET Request with the pk of the logged in user via an AJAX call but can't seem to filter specifically against that. I'd be grateful for any help!

Here is my model:

```
class UserConnections(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="following", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    followed = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="followers", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here are the relevant serializers:

```
class UserConnectionListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserConnections
        fields = ['follower','followed']

class UserConnectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserConnections
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 2
```

Here is the views.py

```
# gets list of who logged in user is following
class FollowingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.UserConnectionListSerializer
    queryset = UserConnections.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            return serializers.UserConnectionSerializer

        return self.serializer_class

        def get_followers(request):
            if request.method == "GET":
                user_id = self.request.GET.get('current_user_id', None)
                return UserConnections.objects.filter(follower__id=user_id)


# gets list of followers who follow logged-in user
class FollowerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.UserConnectionListSerializer
    queryset = UserConnections.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            return serializers.UserConnectionSerializer

        return self.serializer_class

        def get_followers(request):
            if request.method == "GET":
                user_id = self.request.GET.get('current_user_id', None)
                return UserConnections.objects.filter(followed__id=user_id)
```

Comment: why did you define a `get_followers` method and dont use it anywhere? In order to achieve what you are trying to do, rename the `get_followers` to `get_queryset`

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, I tried what you suggested and the result hasn't changed unfortunately.

Comment: Is the indentation correct?

Comment: The indentation is as above in OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `get_queryset`:

```py
class FollowingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...

    # The indentation is in `class` level
    def get_queryset(self):
        user_id = self.request.GET.get('current_user_id', None)
        return UserConnections.objects.filter(follower__id=user_id)
```

and for `FollowerViewSet`:

```py
class FollowerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_id = self.request.GET.get('current_user_id', None)
        return UserConnections.objects.filter(followed__id=user_id)
```

Comment: Thank you the only change I had to make to this solution was to change ``def get_queryset(request)`` to ``def get_queryset(self)`` then it worked like a charm!

Comment: @vygrdev ah, sorry, my bad

Comment: Appreciate your help!